# How to extend jQuery's ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is rather a syntax question I am going to explain it jQuery's ajax functionality.

Let's say I want to control `dataType` of all ajax request according to `url`. For example url's with parameter `&parseJSON=true` should have a dataType of `'JSON'` automatically.

For example:

```
$.myajax({url:'http://example.com&parseJSON=true'})
```

should be equivalent to

```
$.ajax({url:'http://example.com&parseJSON=true', dataType: 'JSON'})
```

Basically, I need to check for URL and add dataType parameter if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with an [ajax prefilter](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/):

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options ) {
  // If datatype isn't set and the url contains our param,
  if ( !options.dataType && options.url.includes('parseJSON=true') ) {
    // return "json" to change the datatype to json
    return "json";
  }
});
```

This doesn't change anything about how you use `$.ajax`, `$.post`, or `$.get` other than that you no longer have to specify the dataType if the url parameter is present.